# Counting the amount of instances of a certain string in a list of objects, then formatting it in a certain way

Tags: c#

I have a list of objects which all contain a certain string. When I enumerate through them, I want to be able to identify all the matching ones and group them together, then format them all into a string like so: A005(x3), B006(x5), C002(x7),D001(x9).

Can anyone shed some light on a good way to do this?

Comment: What research have you done on how to group strings in C#?  What problems have you had with your own attempted solutions or research into this problem?

Comment: Can you post what light you have tried?

Comment: Post the code for whatever you've already tried.

Comment: I found that this problem was easy to approach in theory, but became increasingly hard for me when I got down to coding.(I should mention I'm a relatively novice programmer). I have tried to iterate through the list via foreach only to realize I have no way of "connecting" the values so that I could display them. To simplify my request, all I want is to have an array of data which holds the text value adjacent to the amount of times it appeared on the list.

Comment: Did you consider the GroupBy with a custom predicate?

Answer (score 1):

This code should give you the desired result assuming you have a collection of strings.

```
strList.GroupBy(x => x)
.Select(x => string.Format("{0}(x{1})", x.Key, x.Count()));
```

Here is a test program:

```
var values = new[] {"A005", "B006", "C002", "D001",
            "B006", "A005", "D001", "C002", "A005" };

var uniqueValues = values
                .GroupBy(x => x)
                .Select(x => string.Format("{0}(x{1})", x.Key, x.Count()));

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", uniqueValues));
```

Produces this output:

```
A005(x3), B006(x2), C002(x2), D001(x2)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I have tried to use your code and this is the output I received:     System.Linq.Lookup`2+Grouping[System.String,test1.Grouping] (My list is made of objects, not strings. I have tried to modify the code by doing so: GroupBy(x => x.param), but it didn't seem to work. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.